# AWS Cloudfront is not getting my latest javascript file that is versioned

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am implementing AWS Cloudfront versioning for my javascript and css files in order for the Cloudfront cache to be updated automatically so that I don't have to manually invalidate my files.  I am hosting a static web site content in S3.  My process for deploying new changes is as follows.  Build the web site using webpack which automatically hashes my js and css files.  Web pack also updates the reference to the js and css files in my index.html file (not this file is not versioned).  I then copy the newly generated static web site from my dist folder to my S3 bucket.  According to the documentation I should see my changes automatically without having to invalidate every file in the distribution however I do not.  I'm wondering if I'm missing a step.  At first I thought that maybe the index.html needs to be versioned but the documentation specifically says not to version the Root Document Object.  So my question is... what am I missing?  Does the index.html file which has the new version of my js and css files need to be versioned as well?  If so how can I accomplish this?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ReplacingObjects.html

Page 46 of: https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Storage/Building%20Static%20Websites%20on%20AWS.pdf

Comment: *"According to the documentation I should see my changes automatically without having to invalidate every file in the distribution"*  According to which documentation, where?  Citations, please.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ReplacingObjects.html "With versioning, you don't have to wait for an object to expire before CloudFront begins to serve a new version of it, and you don't have to pay for object invalidation."

Comment: Got it.  The underlying assumption here is that your index.html file will have an appropriately short lifetime specified by its `Cache-Control` header so that browsers and CloudFront will not cache it for as long of a period as they will cache the versioned assets.

Comment: Right, so this means I need to add cli/api calls to update the Cache-Control every time I upload a new index.html.  I can do this but it seems tedious.  If the index.html is replaced, so are all the custom attributes.

Comment: You can set all of the metadata, including `Cache-Control` in the upload request, itself, when uploading the file to S3.  There is no need to make a second request.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a long time. Eventually I found the following to work:

1. Upload new files to s3
2. Invalidate Cloundfront distribution
3. Add cache-control settings to index.html

For the final step, you can use the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/index.html s3://bucket/index.html 
--metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control max-age=0
```

Comment: too bad i really needed much further explanation am not guru in this ! can you optimize your answer more? step1 1 and 2 and 3 is not clear to me